# Autocomplete UI Issue

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete, internet-explorer-7

I'm doing a website UI and I came across this problem in IE7.

As the image below shows, when I search a company it's not displaying properly.
It workers in all other browsers except IE7.
It should be on top (search results).

Can any one help me on this?

For reference please visit: http://piyasanet.hurriyet.com.tr/borsa/endeksler-sektorler

Thank You !

http://shareimage.org/images/1f1xf586prss0qhqrx0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) sharing buttons -- try adding z-index to `#hurriyet-companySearch-widget-wrap` like so:

```css
#hurriyet-companySearch-widget-wrap {
    z-index: 3000;
}
```

2) flash chart -- set the `wmode` attribute to opaque (sorry I cannot figure out how the SWF file is embedded, though it worked when I changed the value using IE developer toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `z-index`, to put in a higher number for the drop down (auto complete) so that it comes above other elements.

Comment: Actually i added z-index as 3000 but still its the same.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `z-index` to work, you need to `position` the parent as well as the child. The parent also needs to have a `z-index` value. Give the parent a lower `z-index` than the child and you shouldn't run into any problems.